# Using result from a function to access a julia array

Tags: julia

I'm new to julia and have a problem.  I have an array, y.

```
y = rand (5, 10)
y [1. 1] = 0
```

Running this gives me an error

```
for j=1:d   
    x_filt [j, 1] = y [j, findfirst (y [j, :])]
end

ERROR: syntax: missing separator in array expression
```

But this doesn't

```
for j=1:d   # fix to 1st obs if 1st tick is missing
    temp = findfirst (y [j, :])
    x_filt [j, 1] = y [j, temp];        
end
```

Can someone explain how to make the first version work?  Or at least explain why it doesn't?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I guess you meant `y[1, 1] = 0`? I get an error if I use `y [1. 1] = 0`.

Julia has *space sensitive syntax* in some contexts, notable inside brackets `[]`.
Some examples:

```
julia> max(1, 2)
2

julia> max (1, 2)
2

julia> [max(1, 2)]
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2

julia> [max (1, 2)]
1x2 Array{Any,2}:
 max  (1,2)

julia> [1 + 2]
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3

julia> [1 +2]
1x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
```

In your first example, the call to `findfirst` in

```
x_filt [j, 1] = y [j, findfirst (y [j, :])]
```

is interpreted as two space-separated items, `findfirst` and `(y [j, :])]`. Julia then complains that they are separated by a space and not a comma.

In your second example, you were able to circumvent this since the call to `findfirst` in

```
temp = findfirst (y [j, :])
```

is no longer in a space sensitive context.

I would recommend that when writing Julia code, you should never put a space between the function name and parenthesis `(` in a function call or the variable and bracket `[` in indexing, because the code will be treated differently in space sensitive contexts. E.g., your first example without the extra spaces

```
for j=1:d   
    x_filt[j, 1] = y[j, findfirst(y[j, :])]
end
```

works fine (provided that you define `d` and `x_filt` appropriately first).